# Woocommerce checkout page css is not displaying correctly

Tags: woocommerce

My woocommerce checkout page is displaying incorrectly. The 'ship to a different address' is overlapping order details. Also when customers try to process an order, it says agree to terms and conditions, yet there is no checkbox on the page. Please help. The website is fdlamb.com

Comment: Hi. Actually there is a checkbox in the page, just to the right side of the "ship to a different address' label. Any modification you had made to your theme? It seems its ocupying the space of the Paypal button.¿Have you deactive some plugins to check if there is any conflict?

Comment: It's a theme based issue, because when I switched themes, the page displayed everything. The theme is woocommerce storefront.

Answer (score 0):

My reason to ask if you have made some changes or installed new plug-ins, is because in some ocasions plug-ins can change the properties of the template, causing some conflicts. So ***deactivating all plugs-ins and seeing if that fix the issue*** can help to know more to what cause the issue in first place.

Also you could just **delete your theme and reinstalling**, to return to the default CSS, as im seeing your theme doesn't have a lot of customization.

Anyway, i don't know a lot but I have move some CSS to the property of the button to see if it fix itself.

```
.checkbox {
    position: inherit;
    top: 7px;
    right: 12px;
}
```

This is how it appears to me with that code. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfebb.jpg

Comment: I'm reinstalling the theme now, but if that doesn't work, I'll use the checkbox css you created. Should I put that in custom css on the checkout page? Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Yes, your theme (in this case Storefront) has a section for custom CSS.